# This question is regarding the match and sort oprimization is MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62c3aa311984f666ef75d1n7"),
    
    "eventCode" : "332",
   
   
   
    "time" : 1657008013000.0,
 
    "dat" : "61558575921c023a93f81362",
 
}
```

This is how a document looks like, now I need to calculate some value for which I am using aggregation pipeline and I am using the match and sort operators first, what I am using is.

```
 $match: {
        dat: { $regex: "^" + eventStat.dat },
        time: {
          $gte: eventStat.time.from,
          $lte: eventStat.time.to,
        },
      },

$sort: { time: 1 }
```

So I am using this two opeartors in the pipeline first,

Now Mongodb Document says that aggregation will always implement match first before sort but in some cases it performs sort first, I am not sure but I think that happens when there is a index on field key used in sort not present in match and Mongodb decides it better to sort first.
Here I am using time in both match and sort so I want to know that is there still any case possible where sort might happen before match?
If yes, I read that a dummy project operator can force it to match first but what exactly is a dummy project opeartor?

Comment: May I ask what `dat` and `time` represent here? Are you storing a timestamp in two different fields (one for the day and one for the time)?

Comment: dat is a string used for identification  and time is "unix time"

Answer (score 0):

Most questions about how the database is executing a query can be answered (or at least further reasoned about) by inspecting the explain plan(s) associated with the operation(s). Let's first address a few of your statements directly before turning to inspect explain plans ourselves.

> Now Mongodb Document says that aggregation will always implement match first before sort

Where does it say this?

In general, all databases are required to provide results that are semantically valid relative to the query that the client issued. This gets mentioned often when SQL is being discussed as it is a "declarative language". This means that users describe *what* data they want rather than how to retrieve that data.

MongoDB's aggregation framework is a bit less declarative than SQL. Or said another way, the aggregation framework is a little more descriptive in how to do things. This is because the ordering that the stages are defined in for a pipeline help define the semantics of the results. If, for example, one were to `$project` out a field first and *then* attempt to use that (no longer present) field in a subsequent stage (such as a `$match` or `$group`), MongoDB would **not** make any adjustments to how it processes the pipeline to make that field available to that later stage. This is because the user specifically requested the removal of that stage earlier in the pipeline which is part of the semantics for the overall pipeline.

Based on this (and another factor that we will talk about next), I would be surprised to see any documentation suggesting that the database always performs a match stage before a sort stage.

> but in some cases it performs sort first, I am not sure but I think that happens when there is a index on field key used in sort not present in match and Mongodb decides it better to sort first.

Again returning to generalizations about all databases, one of their primary jobs is to return data to clients as efficiently as possible. So as long as their approach at executing the query does not logically change the results based on the semantics expressed by the client in the query, the database can gather the results in any manner that it thinks will be the most effective.

For aggregation specifically, this most commonly means that stages will either get reordered or combined altogether for execution. Some of the changes that the database will attempt to do are outlined on the [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Logically, filtering data and then sorting it yields the same results as sorting the data and then filtering it. So indeed, one of the optimizations outlined on that page is indeed [reordering `$match` and `$sort` stages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-sort----match-sequence-optimization).

The important thing to keep in mind here is mentioned at the very top of that page. The database "***attempts** to reshape the pipeline for improved performance*", but how effective these adjustments are depend on other factors. The biggest factor for many of these is the presence (or absence) of an associated index to support the (reordered) pipeline.

> Here I am using time in both match and sort so I want to know that is there still any case possible where sort might happen before match?

Unless you are explicitly forcing the database to use a particular plan (such as by hinting it), there is always a *chance* that it will choose to do something unexpected. Databases are quite good at picking optimal plans though and are always improving with each new release, so ideally we'd leave the system to do its work and not try to do that work for the database (with hints or otherwise). In your particular situation, I believe we can design an approach that is highly optimized for both the `$match` and the `$sort` setting it up for success.

> If yes, I read that a dummy project operator can force it to match first but what exactly is a dummy project opeartor?

It sounds like this is also asking about other ways in which we could manually influence plan selection. We are going to stay away from that as it is fragile, not something we should rely on long term, and unnecessary for our purposes anyway.

---

##### Inspecting Explain

So what happens if we have an index on `{ time: 1 }` and we run the aggregation? Well, the `explain` output (on `6.0`) shows us the following:

```
  queryPlanner: {
    parsedQuery: {
      '$and': [
        { time: { '$lte': 100 } },
        { time: { '$gte': 0 } },
        { dat: { '$regex': '^ABC' } }
      ]
    },
    ...
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: { dat: { '$regex': '^ABC' } },
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: { time: 1 },
        indexBounds: { time: [ '[0, 100]' ] }
        ...
      }
    },
```

Notice that there is no `$sort` stage at all. What has happened is that the database realized that it could use the `{ time: 1 }` index to do two things at the same time:

1. Filter the data according to the range predicates on the `time` field.
2. Walk the index in the requested sort order without having to manually do so.

So if we go back to the main original question of whether aggregation will perform the match or sort first, we now see that a third option is for the database to do both activities them at the same time!

At the very least, you should have an index on `{ time: 1 }`.

Ideally you would instead have a compound index on the other field (`dat`) as well. There is a bit of a wrinkle here in that you are currently applying a regex operator against the field. If the filter were a direct equality match, the guidance would be easy (prepend `dat: 1` as the first key in the compound index).

Without knowing more about your situation, it's unclear which of the two compound indexes the database could use more effectively to support this operation. If the regex filter on `dat` is highly selective, then `{ dat: 1, time: 1 }` will probably be ideal. It will require a manual sort, but that can all be done after scanning the index before retrieving the full documents. If the regex filter on `dat` is *not* very selective, then `{ time: 1, dat: 1 }` may be ideal. This would prevent the need to manually sort, but will result in some additional index key scanning.

In either case, examining `explain` output may be helpful in finding the approach that is best suited for your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks for the eplaination,
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#sort-match-sequence-optimization
This is the link to the mongoDb docs that says match comes before sort

Comment: Right, the optimizer _attempts_ to do that, but won't always as I was describing above. Depending on the indexes that you have, the database may either choose to do the `$match` first or may choose to walk the index in sorted order filtering as it goes (e.g. doing them both at the same time). Is there something additional that I can help clarify in this answer?

Comment: No I got you thanks for solution.

Comment: Glad it was useful!  Please consider accepting the answer if it helped so that others know the question has been resolved

Comment: I would but I cannot upvote it due to less reputation points and I also cannot seem to find any option to accept it, I upvoted though and it showed your feedback was accepted